# Missing parameter received in the controller when passing from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have include some models in my asp.net mvc4 view so I have create a base view model which contains the two other models:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public FirstTypeModel FirstViewModel { get; set; }
        public SecondTypeModel SecondViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the view:

```
 @model MyNamespace.Models.CustomViewModel

 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddFields", "Configure", FormMethod.Post))
 { 
         (...)
                 <div id="componentId">
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId, new { @id = "componentIdLabel" })
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId, Model.FirstViewModel.CompTypeItems, new { @name = "SelectedCompTypeId", @id = "componentType" })
                 </div>
         (...)

                 <input id="submitAddComp" type="submit" value="@Resource.ButtonTitleAddComponent" />

 }
```

in my controller:

```
public ActionResult AddFields(string param1, string param2, string param3, int selectedCompTypeId)
{
 ...
}
```

when click on the submit button I am getting selectedCompTypeId as null (param1, param2 and param3 are passed correctly), but if I watch below request from within the controller it has the correct value:

```
Request["FirstViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId"]
```

so how to pass the correct parameter to the controller in order to selectedCompTypeId not to be null?

Note: including only one model, before creating the base model which contains the others two, it was working correctly. Before, lamba expression was m => m.SelectedCompTypeId instead m => m.FirstViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId.

Comment: Added information to my answer... please have a look.

Comment: Did you try the answer below? If it worked for you accept the answer... if not please comment what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor initializing your first and second model.

```
namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public CustomViewModel()
        {
            FirstViewModel = new FirstTypeModel();
            SecondViewModel = new SecondTypeModel();
        }

        public FirstTypeModel FirstViewModel { get; set; }
        public SecondTypeModel SecondViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
But instead of passing all parameters one by one, just put the Model itself in your AddFields action. The problem you are facing, is that as you are using `DropDownListFor` the name of the parameter is "FirstViewModel.SelectedCompTypeId" and not just "SelectedCompTypeId" as you have it in your controller.

There are 2 options, one better than the other:

**OPTION 1:**

Instead of using

```
public ActionResult AddFields(string param1, string param2, string param3, int selectedCompTypeId)
{
 ...
}
```

use it this way

```
public ActionResult AddFields(CustomViewModel model)
{
 ...
}
```

this is better, because if you add more fields tomorrow, you don't need to change actions signature, and the binding is done by the framework.

**OPTION 2:** Change the `DropDownListFor`  for a `DropDownList`, and this way, you can say which is the name of the parameter, and make it work. It is far preferrable the first option... is cleaner.

```
@Html.DropDownList("selectedCompTypeId", theList, "Select one...", new { @class = "myNiceCSSStyle"})
```

Comment: i have done it and the same behaviour. Also model initialization can be done in the controller as well.