# Trying to know which element is currently selected on a @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a custom view model like this:

```
namespace MyCustomNamespace.Models
{
    public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public CustomViewModel()
        {
            FirstViewModel = new FirstModel ();
            SecondViewModel = new SecondModel ();
        }

        public FirstModel FirstViewModel { get; set; }
        public SecondModel SecondViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyCustomNamespace.Models
{
   public class FirstModel 
   {
      public string id { get; set; }
      public string text { get; set; }

      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
      {
         (...)
      }

       (...)
   }
}
```

SecondModel is similar to FirstModel.

in my view i do using razor:

```
@model MyCustomNamespace.Models.CustomViewModel

(...)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstViewModel.Id, Model.FirstViewModel.Items)

(...)
```

I populate the dropdownlist with a model.

I am trying to know which is the current selected element in the dropdownlist shown above, but i do not know how.... maybe through the model? but how?

**Updated:**
This is my real model type, above was an example about what i was doing. FirstModel would be ComponentTypeModel in this case:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System;
using Resources;

namespace MyCustomNamespace.Models
{
    public class ComponentTypeModel
    {
        private readonly List<ComponentType> componentTypes;

        public ComponentTypeModel()
        {
            using (ConfigContext dbContext = new ConfigContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    componentTypes = dbContext.ComponentTypes.ToList();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //EventLogger.LogException(ex);                    
                }
            }
        }

        [Display(Name = "Component Type")]
        public int SelectedCompTypeId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompTypeItems
        {
            get
            {
                var allCompTypes = componentTypes.Select(f => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = f.ComponentTypeId.ToString(),
                    Text = f.Name
                });

                return DefaultCompTypeItem.Concat(allCompTypes);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultCompTypeItem
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
                                               {
                                                   Value = "-1",
                                                   Text = "Select a component type"
                                               }, 
                                         count: 1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `m.FirstViewModel.Id` and you can access in client side `$('#your-ddl-id').val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your models, you are using

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items
      {
         (...)
      }
```

That is fine, but doing so, you need to set manually the selected item. I suggest you to use a `SelectList` instead of a list of SelectListItems.

So, in your ViewModel, you need:

```
public SelectList Items {get; set;}
```

In your controller you populate that `SelectList`:

```
var myItems = GetMyCollectionOfItems(); //The list to display in the DropDownList
model.FirstViewModel.Items = new SelectList(myItems, "NameOfValueField", "NameOfTextField", selectedValue); //The selected value is optional
```

Then in your View you use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstViewModel.Id, Model.FirstViewModel.Items, "--- Select Item---", new { @id = "firstModelID" })
```

Check that is the same code you used, but this way, is the SelectList who knows which item is selected and you don't need to do nothing manually. Just load the id of the select items in the SelectList constructor.

Then, if you need to know in client side which is the selected item, in order to use it in Javascript to hide something or something like that, you can do what the other people answers:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var mySelectedValue = $('#firstModelID').val();
   alert(mySelectedValue);  
});
```

If you need to know when the select value changes:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#firstModelID').change(function() {
       alert($('#firstModelID').val());
   });
});
```

**AFTER YOUR UPDATE:**

All the code you have in the Model, can be greatly simplified using the code in this answer.

You should do a little change: Make the

```
[Display(Name = "Component Type")]
        public int SelectedCompTypeId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Component Type")]
        public int? SelectedCompTypeId { get; set; }  //Now this is nullable
```

If you do this way, you don't need to add the default item thing... just use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstViewModel.Id, Model.FirstViewModel.Items, "Select a component type", new { @id = "firstModelID" })
```

Then in your controller, you can see it is Null you do the equivalent a what you do when you received the "-1".

Now, all the database access should be away of the model. The model is much cleaner this way:

```
public class ComponentTypeModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Component Type")]
        public int? SelectedCompTypeId { get; set; }
        public SelectLis CompTypeItems { get; set:}

    }
```

Then in your controller you do:

```
var model = new ComponentTypeModel();
model.CompTypeItems = new SelectList(dbContext.ComponentTypes.Select(x => x.Name, x.ComponentTypeId), "ComponentTypeId", "Name");
```

If you want to have one of them selected by default (as you usually do in an Edit view), you do this:

```
var model = new ComponentTypeModel();
model.CompTypeItems = new SelectList(dbContext.ComponentTypes.Select(x => x.Name, x.ComponentTypeId), "ComponentTypeId", "Name", myDefaultValue);  //where the myDefaultValue is an int
```

The razor code in your view should remain the same, since all the information about selected item, collection of items, fields to be mapped remains in the controller and model.

Comment: see my updated code, this is the real one. I was posted an example of what I was doing. Thanks for you great and detailed example.

Comment: BTW, this is the second answer I provide to you in this same issue... and you didn't accept neither answer.Please accept the ones you thin that helped you. This is the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19084479/7720

Answer (score 2):

If you trying to know it before submitting the form (on client side)

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstViewModel.Id, Model.FirstViewModel.Items, "--- Select Item---", new { @id = "firstModelID" })
```

and you could check its value by: `$('#firstModelID').val();`

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to identify that in C# on the client side, you'd have to use jQuery/JavaScript for that, something like:

```
$("#FirstViewModel_Id").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var Id = $("#FirstViewModel_Id").val();

alert(Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected value will be in the `Id` property of the posted model (`FirstViewModel`) after a post to the server.

You can access the

If you want to get the selected value on the client you can use:

```
$("#FirstViewModel_Id").val();
```

or

```
$("#FirstViewModel_Id option:selected").val();
```

if the first one doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers here, you can also do like this:

```
$("#FirstViewModel_Id option:selected").val();
```